# I'm trying to make a localstorage for a shopping cart

Tags: javascript

```
numPlass++;
let names = [];
var set = cart_item.childNodes[numPlass].innerHTML;
names.push(set);
let local = JSON.stringify(names);

localStorage.setItem('name' ,local)
```

It only shows me the last one and doesn't put more than one in the array

Comment: You start by creating names as an empty array and then adding one childNode. You then store this in localStorage.  I think you are missing some code to read localStorage before adding to the list.  The way the code is right now localStorage will always contain only 1 element.

Comment: Could you please send me an example of a revised code thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
let names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name'))|| [];
var set = cart_item.childNodes[numPlass].innerHTML;
names.push(set);
localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(names));
```

Comment: I'm really sorry but he shows me an error  names.push is not a function

Comment: I've changed it, can you try again

Comment: I just arranged the code for that               let names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name')) || [];
Made me really happy thanks for everything good man !!